# mkString and getOrElse("")

Tags: scala

Is there any difference between

```
abc.mkString
```

and

```
abc.getOrElse("")
```

when `abc` is an `Option[String]`?

Comment: Not really, but the second appears a little clearer to me.

Comment: As far as functionality goes, I'm pretty sure they're the same. Implementation wise, the first one first converts an `Option` to `List` ([implicit conversion to `Iterable`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Option.scala)) and then uses `mkString`, second one just does a check and returns appropriate value passed by name (implementation in link above too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. These are identical operations. However, their implementation may differ and one may be more efficient than the other.